# HTML, CSS Random Sized Self Aligning Justified Image Gallery

Tags: html, css, dynamic, responsive, image-gallery

I am creating an image gallery populated with a dynamic sized amount of images, the PHP and HTML are as follows;

```
<?php
$dirname = "Pictures/";
?>

<ul class="gallery">

<?php

$images = glob("" . $dirname . "*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG,JPEG,PNG,GIF}", GLOB_BRACE);

foreach ($images as $image) 
{
    $File = pathinfo($image);
?>

<li class="container">
    <a href="<?php echo $url.$image; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $url.$image; ?>" alt=""></a>
</li>

<?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

The css I have is as follows;

```
.gallery 
{
    line-height: 0;
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -webkit-column-gap:   5px;
    -moz-column-count:    5;
    -moz-column-gap:      5px;
    column-count:         5;
    column-gap:           5px;  
    align-content: stretch;
    list-style: none;
}

.gallery li
{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    margin-bottom:5px!important;
    border:1px solid #dfe1e5;
}

.container img
{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

This code I have so far doesn't allow me to randomly display the images while justifying the bottom row so the whole gallery is more rectangular, as follows;

[Justified Random Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK6UZ.png)

Also, this code is in columns, what I would like is a more random flow instead of breaking things up into columns.

Can someone give some advice of a better way to achieve the goal of a random sized self aligning justified image gallery using CSS and HTML only.

I created a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/awhe61kg/ for those who request.

As a side note, what I would like to achieve at the least is like the unitegallery theme https://unitegallery.net/index.php?page=tiles-justified, but without the use of Javascript if at all possible. The reason I don't want to use this gallery is because I've tried it and it is glitchy. Although it is a beautiful design which I would like to replicate in CSS and HTML.

** FIXED ISSUE BELOW **

I can nearly achieve the unitegallery behavior with CSS flex boxes alone as follows;

```
.gallery 
{
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    list-style: none;
    font-size:0;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.gallery li
{
    flex-direction: row;
    flex:20 20 auto;
    width: auto !important;
    height:200px;
    max-width:400px; <-----------causes the problem, remove and its fixed
    margin-bottom:5px!important;
    border:1px solid #dfe1e5;
}

.container img
{
    min-width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Although I'm having an issue currently with the top row not stretching correctly at certain widths in responsive design mode.

** FIXED **

Here is a JSFiddle with the flex box image gallery and the element which was causing the problem commented out https://jsfiddle.net/ag9s2qdt/.

Comment: so  you have a bunch of images you want to display, and the goal is to get them edge-to-edge on the browser window with no gaps, is that right?

Comment: I created this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/awhe61kg/ which shows what I have, so the gaps in between the images I want to keep. I just don't want columns, and I would like the bottom to be flat like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK6UZ.png. I was thinking about maybe floating the li's to the left and then trying to figure out the bottom row...But I don't want to go down the wrong route, so I asked for advice from CSS ninjas.

Comment: I don't really know a lot about PHP I can help you with some of js code

Comment: I was trying to steer away from js, I'm fine with the PHP and HTML, it's the CSS that I need the advice on...But if js is the only way to go, then I am open to learning...

Comment: I know enough JS to reverse engineer things and get things to work...

Comment: so is your main problem the gaps between the images?

Comment: No, I want the gaps between the images, my main problem is figuring out the best way to display images with random widths and heights in a way that does not us columns and justifies all the images so the bottom of the list is flat and not like a jig-saw effect at the bottom. I am trying to achieve this type of random layout https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK6UZ.png, while keeping the images in a whole rectangle, where the inner child list items that hold the images align with the edges of the parent container.

Comment: So all the edges are neat and tidy and not like a shed at the bottom. I do not want columns, I want a better flow, so maybe li's floating left where they as a whole make a rectangle. If you cross reference this example https://jsfiddle.net/awhe61kg/ with this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK6UZ.png, you can see the difference. Where the code example is what I have, the image is what I want to achieve.

Comment: The unitegallery link here is what I would like to achieve https://unitegallery.net/index.php?page=tiles-justified. The reason I don't want to use this gallery is because I've tried it and it is glitchy. Although it is a beautiful design which I would like to replicate in CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The page you link to ([here](https://unitegallery.net/index.php?page=tiles-justified)) just uses rows instead of columns. If you want justified rows of images with just HTML and CSS, you can do this:

```css
.justified {
  text-align: justify;
}

.justified:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.justified img {
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="justified">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/19/18/57/godafoss-1840758_1280.jpg" />
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1014/6016/4000.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1013/4256/2832.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1009/5000/7502.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1006/3000/2000.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1005/5760/3840.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1003/1181/1772.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1002/4312/2868.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1000/5626/3635.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/100/2500/1656.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Of course, the gaps between each image can be wide, and you're responsible for making sure there isn't a weird amount of images on the last row. JavaScript would help tremendously with the calculations for actually getting a good result here, but to each his own.